# Using coax cable to extend network into WIFI dead-zone

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I have a bedroom in my house that gets very poor Wifi. I have an Arris device (a modem, wifi-point and switch all-in-one from my internet provider ARRIS TG862G-CT) and don't want to move it because right now it is in a spot that covers 90% of the house well with Wifi. The previous owner of the house had co-ax installed in almost all the rooms and there is a co-ax that goes from near the Arris device to the low-signal room. Can I use that?

What would be a good hard-wired way to get good internet access to that room? It already has co-ax and I want to use that because pulling new ethernet wire is a mess. The Arris unit has available ethernet sockets I can use. Can someone give suggestions as to what to do? Are there adapters that go from ethernet to co-ax and then on the other side I would go from co-ax to ethernet, right? Going hard-wired is preferable to just a Wifi-booster because it is more reliable and I want to be able to make phone-calls too.

Can someone recommend a solution? I don't even know what the hardware is called. Should I just get messy and pull in new ethernet Cat 5? That is a last resort, but then what hardware do I need for that? Please talk to me like a N00b because I barely know the difference between a router and a switch. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, they are called Moca adapters. Power line adapters could also be an option. I'm not sure about Moca v2.0, but Moca v1.0 had the draw back of being simplex. A lot of power line adapters are also simplex. Make sure you read the product specifications carefully.

Comment: @Tim: Do you mean "half-duplex"?

Comment: @user1686, yes. It was pretty late when I wrote that comment. Half-duplex is what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get two MoCA adapters. I've used them in the past, speeds were around 150Mbps which is better than nothing.

They use the coax from your house and run ethernet over it. Early ethernet systems (80s and 90s) were run over coax, so this is not a new concept. This is a modern implementation of it.

You need a minimum of two adapters, but can use as many as you ultimately need. Plug one into your internet router, and the other where you want a cabled device to plug in. The cabled device could be another wireless access point if you desired.

Comment: Moca v2.0 gets close to 1000Mbit these days. Obviously there are plenty of variables including cable type that can affect the advertised speeds though.